# Display base64 image from url to objectUrl

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, image, base64

There is a base64 image in the db and I need to fetch the image and store its localhost url into a variable. I need to use the fetch function because the image is authenticated. I am not sure if I have to use blob() or arraybuffer() or text() in the response.

```
fetch(url, {
method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    Authorization: '',
    'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'
  }
})
.then(response => response.blob())
.then(data => {
    const fileUrl = URL.createObjectUrl(data);
    console.log(fileUrl);
})
```

Apparently the database should return the base64 string. My plan is to create a blob then create an object url from it and store it. When I visit that object url, the page is black with nothing on it. The blob size is 16 too. What does that mean? Is the base64 string in the data?

Comment: If your server-side code returns a base64 encoded string, then use `response.text()`

Comment: @Phil when I use text() and console log data, it prints [object Promise]. Is this an error or is the image in a different format

Comment: Replace `response.blob()` with `response.text()`, then in the next `then()`, `data` should be the base64 encoded string

Comment: I did that and it prints out [object Promise] @Phil